# MASM - very beginner proggie

Tags: assembly, overflow, cycle

I am learning assembly just for 1-2 hours, so forgive me for my possible stupidity :)

I am trying to write a program which calculates amount of "1" bits in some byte.

The problem itself seems to be a "inc bl" opcode. I guess have an error in cycle, so bl overflows. And it is infact the problem with cycle, because when I removed "inc bl" the program was working fine (except that fact it didn't calculate anything), but I can't figure out whats wrong.

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall
.data
n BYTE 21
count BYTE 0
.code
start:
  mov bl, 0
lp:
  cmp bl, 7
  jz endl
  inc bl
  shr n, 1
  jc inccount
  jmp lp
inccount:
  inc count
  jmp lp


endl:

end start
```

Comment: Lol, no. Just some basic crap I decided to do. Activity is the only road to knowledge, you know.

Comment: @user1066992: So, what do you think should happen when the CPU executes `jz endl` and continues from `endl:`? Also, where are DS and ES set to something meaningful for this code?

Comment: Probably, after jz endl, it should end itself?

Comment: @Alex: OP is programming 32 bit assembly in MASM32, not 16 bit.

Answer (score 2):

You have several problems here. Mainly it is that you are not calling the OS to exit the process. The solution is to call [ExitProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682658%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
.386
include \masm32\include\masm32rt.inc
.data
n BYTE 255
count BYTE 0
.code
start:
  mov bl, 0
lp:
  cmp bl, 8
  jz endl
  inc bl
  shr n, 1
  jc inccount
  jmp lp
inccount:
  inc count
  jmp lp

endl:

  invoke ExitProcess, 0

end start
```

You will notice I included `masm32rt.inc` which contains the function prototype and the `.lib` file for ExitProcess. On top of this, the comparison for bl should be 8 to ensure you have shifted 8 times, not 7.

The reason your program appeared to be crashing before was because it was not being exited properly, not because of any overflow issue. If you remove `inc bl` then it will never terminate, hiding the original problem. (Actually not strictly true, it should eventually overflow back to the 7 because you would get an integer overflow and it would wrap).